# Illustrator JS Script Run without app.activeDocument

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have been using Illustrators API to create a script that is able to export `.ai` files swatches into a JSON format.

This however is all by having to open the Illustrator file and click

```
File > Scripts > Run My Script.
```

This is something that is very tedious and was wondering if there was a way in order to take the the files location (file path) and just execute the program using something like Node which will just use my already existing code and my AI file.

Currently I have something that looks along the lines of:

```
var Exporter = function() {
this.swatchGroup = 'ClientColours';
this.myApp = app.activeDocument;
this.chosenSwatchGroup();
this.writeFile(); };
```

What I am thinking is there not a way to instead of having `this.myApp = app.activeDocument;` to rather have something like `this.myApp = Path(../my location);`?

I have been making us of this documentation [Jongware](http://jongware.mit.edu/iljscs6html/iljscs6/) and [Adobe Documentation](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/illustrator/sdk/CC2015_3/Illustrator%20JavaScript%20Scripting%20Reference.pdf) just cant seem to find the answer I am looking for in order to get closer to this sort of automation.

### EDIT

Did some digging and found the application documentation and there is a 'path' property just not sure on its implementation. [Documentation](http://jongware.mit.edu/iljscs6html/iljscs6/pc_Application.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this by providing path. But you have to open that file and that file will be your activeDocument. For eg :

```
var file = File("../your location");
app.open(file);
this.myApp = app.activeDocument;
```

By this, the file at your location will get open in Illustrator and will be activeDocument.